# (ESLint) Cannot find module 'eslint-config-react-app' in VS 2017 react project

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, react-redux

We have a react app in Visual Studio 2017 that shows the following warning messages for every .js file in the project "(ESLint) Cannot find module 'eslint-config-react-app'...". We have the react-scripts package installed that pulled in the eslint-config-react-app package as well. We have tried to install it ourselves in the local projects package.json as well as a global package.

No matter what we do these errors will not go away.

**UPDATED:**
The project folder structure is:

- Project

  - ClientApp

    - public
    - src
    - packages.json
  - Controllers
  - Pages

I have tried putting the following in the packages.json file:

```
"eslintConfig": {
   "extends": "react-app"
}
```

I have tried creating a .eslintrc file in the ClientApp folder as well as moving to the project root folder so it sits at the same level as the ClientApp folder. In the file I had the following:

```
{
    "extends": "react-app"
}
```

I also tried the following in the .eslintrc file:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ]
}
```

When I did this my error changes to "

> (ESLint) ESLint encountered a parsing error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. I removed all .eslintrc files and also removed the ESLint config section of the packages.json file. Then I went into Tools...Options in Visual Studio and searched for ESLint. I then clicked on the button "Reset global .eslintrc". Finally I closed and re-opened the solution and everything is now working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me, but it was:

```
Error: Failed to load plugin react: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-react'
```

I didn't have a .eslintrc in the website root!!! So I added one (there are lots of examples of what it must contain)

Comment: I updated the post with additional details. Still no luck.